# FS permission scenario

Tags: permissions, filesystems, symlink, chmod, hard-link

How can I achieve this files & folders permissions scenario:

Consider these folder:
Folder A: `640 root apache /var/www/A/`
Folder www: `640 root apache /var/www/`
and this linux user:
`id user1`: `uid=1000(user1) gid=1000(user1) groups=1000(user1)`

I want to allow linux user `user1` read/write access *JUST* to folder A, **BUT** don't change folder A owner or group.

I have tried these scenarios but none of them were desirable:

- add `user1` to group `apache`:
  cons: `user1` will be able to read other files at `/var/www/`.
- hard-link a folder(ex. folder B) in `user1`'s home to `/var/www/A/` and set proper permissions on folder B rather than A:
  cons: hard-links to directories not possible on cross-devices.
- add `user1` to `sudoers`:
  cons: complexity of `user1`, plus, `user1` may broke owner/group policy and/or permissions of folder A by human-error.

any idea?

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to change the group of folder `A`? That really is the best way of achieving what you want.

Comment: @0x004D44 there's no way to change permissions in such a way that (a) owner and group don't change, and (b) folder is only accessible from certain user accounts.

Comment: i can't change the group of folder `A` @terdon because that folder is managed by another admin account & i don't have access and/or permission to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to give `user1` access to /var/www/A because you visit the content managed by `user1` via http://your.domain/A? Why not have apache redirect the content to a directory under the users home directory?

```
Alias /A/ /path/to/users/homedir/A
```

This will achieve the result and not have to change group/user ownership/permissions of the /path/to/users/homedir/A.

However if you want to do it by file permissions, you will only be able to achieve it *by* changing ownership/permissions of /var/www *and* /var/www/A.

Create a 'new group' (most unixes provide a `groupadd` command), add both apache and user1 to it. Change the group ownership of /var/www/A to this 'new group' (with either `chown` or `chgrp`). Set the permissions to disallow access to rw for 'new group' and 'other users' to the /var/www directory (`chmod 711 /var/www`) and give access to the 'new group' for /var/www/A (`chmod g+rwx /var/www/A`).

References:

[Apache Alias Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)

Comment: no you assumed wrong @drav-sloan, `user1` is a Drupal admin which needs to upload/download Drupal Module files to the Multi-site installation Drupal relying in `/var/www/`

Comment: You can still do the above and sym link the directory from /var/www (soft link not hard link) and then set `Options +FollowSymLinks` for that directory.

Comment: it's not just about visiting the content on the web @drav-sloan, the Drupal itself located at `/var/www/` should have read/write access to it's modules directory which in above scenario is folder `A`.

Comment: Setting permissions so the apache process can write to the directory `A` is all that is required - it being outside of /var/www makes no difference (the symlink takes care of both php access and web content). And this gets around your "cannot makes changes to /var/www ownership/permission" problem.

Comment: you are right, i should see the it this way, tnx

Answer (score 1):

Create a group `group1`, add `apache` and `user1` to `group1`, then change the group that owns `/var/www/A` to `group1` using `chgrp` like so:

```
# use `-R' if you want to do this recursively, that is grant `group1' access to 
# all sub-directories of `A' as well as access to `A' itself.

# as a regular user with sudo rights:

sudo chgrp -R group1 /var/www/A 

# as root 

chgrp -R group1 /var/www/A
```

Thus, `user1` will not be a member of apache and so will not be able to read `/var/www`, but will still be able to read `/var/www/A`, while apache will also be able to still read `/var/www/A`.

Lastly, double check that group members have `read/write` access using `chmod` like so:

```
# use `-R' at your own discretion--it acts the same way as `-R' in `chgrp'

# as root 

chmod -R g=rw /var/www/A

# as a regular user with sudo rights

sudo chmod -R g=rw /var/www/A
```

Or something like that.

Comment: `apache` is not an user, it's a group, and i can't add a group to another group in linux, can i?

Comment: @0x004D44 I have no idea, but the general idea would work.  Maybe, you could... I dunno.  There really ought to be a way to add a group to another group, though.